# Two AJAX form submissions, one not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax from to allow me to submit two forms.

I have an add to cart, and an update cart form, both on the same page.

I am using the following code to trigger the add to cart or update cart submission.

```
$('#cart-container').on('submit','form',function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        success: cart
    }); 
    return false; 
});

function cart() {
    var path = '/enter/embed-cart';
    $('#cart-container').fadeTo('fast', 0.5).load(path, function() {
        $('#cart-container').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }); 
}
```

I have tested both forms with my ajax disabled, and they work perfectly, so I know the forms are working correctly.

With the script, the add to cart form is working correctly, but the update form doesnt submit. The strange thing is that the function cart() is running, but when the load() is complete the form has not been updated. I am wondering if have two forms inside the div #cart-container is meaning its only targeting the first (add to cart form), but why would it still run the submission for the update form?

Can anyone see why this would happen?

Here is the stripped down HTML. The forms wont make much sense as they are from a CMS.

```
<div id="cart-container" class="divide clearfix">
    <div id="purchase-submissions" class="grid col-12 bp2-col-6">

        <form method="post" action="/enter"  >
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="cart-btn add-item">
        </form>

    </div> <!-- End of .grid -->

    <div id="cart" class="grid col-12 bp2-col-6">

        <form method="post" action="/enter"  >

            Update form details

        </form> 

    </div> <!-- End of .grid -->

</div> <!-- End of #cart-container-->
```

Thank you

Comment: Including the HTML for the forms would help. Is `#cart-container` the actual form, or a `<div>` containing everything?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Hi Anthony, I have just added the stripped down HTML for you.

Comment: @JudsonTerrell Still the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why  the form is getting updated on a normal submit is because you are refreshing the content on the page(the form) you need to put the form in a div and post it from within that div then refresh that div to see the same result. While ajaxForm submits the content behind the scenes, it does not "update" the form for you. For this to happen, I would put the form and the script in a page, call it into the container div and let the submission happen within that div and refresh the div after. Look into ajaxForm "target" method.

From Malsup site:

// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#output2',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback

```
    // other available options: 
    //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
    //type:      type        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
    //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
    //clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
    //resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 

    // $.ajax options can be used here too, for example: 
    //timeout:   3000 
}; 

// bind to the form's submit event 
$('#myForm2').submit(function() { 
    // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
    // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    // !!! Important !!! 
    // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
    return false; 
});
```

});

If you need me to create an actual example let me know.

Comment: Thanks Judson, I will take a look now. However, doesn't the fact I have a .load() call the same?

Comment: Yes but I think you are needed to post the form back to itself in this case to retain the values.Also, .load should be calling the page that the forms reside on. You are trying to show updated form right? Not some content somewhere like a table or something.

Comment: Another recommendation is always load your content first, then fade in on the callback of the load ;)

Comment: Okay, could you possibly show me an example, as I am getting a little lost here.

Comment: I can but you need to give me an idea of some of the form details you are trying to update

Comment: Okay, have managed to get it working differently than originally wanted. I am still using the .load() function to reload an embed (which has the form in). Is it okay to do it like this? I am now slightly worried that the .load() function is not meant for this from your previous comment.

Comment: This should be fine but typically you could post or get. Load simply does what it says, load content.

Answer (score 0):

Ever considered using [jQuery Forms Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)? It will surely save you from doing such things manually.

Comment: Hi David. I am using it, you can see it in my script :) Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, missed it. Then I would advise to return field values in JSON structure and then load form fields from it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have ids on the forms and I would have a separate jquery call for each one basic on their respective I'd. You are trying to submit a div.

You could also try calling '#cart-container form' since the submit needs to be bound to the form.

Comment: Hi Judson. I have changed the code to this as a test:

 $('#cart-container form').on('submit',function() {
  $('#update_form').ajaxSubmit({
   success: cart
  }); 
  return false; 
 });
 
 function cart() {
  var path = '/enter/embed-cart';
  $('#cart-container').fadeTo('fast', 0.5).load(path, function() {
   $('#cart-container').fadeTo('fast', 1);
  }); 
 }

and added the id #update_cart to the update cart form. The function is being called as before, but the form isn't updating stil...

Comment: Have you tried changing success to complete? Can you place an alert in the callback and verify you are seeing it?

Comment: Thats the weird thing, if I place an alert in the success function its working. But for some reason not updating the form. If I remove the ajax script, and submit the form it works. So its got to be something to do with the script, right?

Comment: @ccdavies You're making two AJAX calls: one to submit the form (via the plugin), the other to update the page content. Are the expected changes from the AJAX form submit happening server-side? If so, the issue would appear to be with the second AJAX call.